# Firebase Databse URL error occurs when I try to use RDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a presence in Cloud Firestore in React + Firebase. I follow [this official docuument](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). Until this, the application has been working on Firestore, and it works well. But this time, it requires both Firestore and RDB to build this.

I tried to fetch `firebase` as usual but the error below occurs:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.
Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().
```

Firestore does work but RDB doesn't work.

**config/firebase.js**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

export default firebase;
```

**app.js**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  const uid = user.uid;
  const userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref("/status/" + uid);

  const isOfflineForDatabase = {
    state: "offline",
    last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  };

  const isOnlineForDatabase = {
    state: "online",
    last_changed: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  };

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(".info/connected")
    .on("value", function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val() == false) {
        return;
      }
      userStatusDatabaseRef
        .onDisconnect()
        .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
        .then(function() {
          userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
        });
    });
});
```

Databse URL is like `https://xxxx.forebaseio.com`.

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL` contains the value you want?

Comment: Given the error you get, it seems that `process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL` does not have the value it must have. You can most easily verify this yourself by including `console.log(firebaseConfig. databaseURL)` right before the call to `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.

Comment: I set up wrong database URL. Thank you guys.